# How to databind a class object to a ViewCell?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need to databind a class object to a custom ViewCell. I used the `{Binding propName}` for the fields on the controls inside the ViewCell. I'm not sure if I am adding the ViewCell correctly since it shows as `[AppName.GridView]` and does not show the control I built. What is the correct way to bind this control with the custom class?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ViewCell  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       Height="50">
   <Frame  HeightRequest="50" Padding="0" Margin="1" BorderColor="blue" CornerRadius="4" BackgroundColor="lightBlue">
    <Grid BindingContext="Binding local:di" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="34"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="btnItem" Text="{Binding itemName}" Clicked="BtnClicked" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" />
            <Label x:Name="lbAmt" Text="{Binding amt}" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="lightBlue" />
            <Label x:Name="lbType" Text="{Binding amtType}" Grid.Column="3" Margin="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="lightBlue" />
        </Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

The code to add the object.

```
        DItem di = new DItem() { itemName = "someName", amt = 1, amtType = xf };
        GridItems gi = new GridItems() { di = di };
        ObservableCollection<GridItems> lv = new ObservableCollection<GridItems>();
        lv.Add(gi);
        lvItems.ItemsSource = lv;
```

Comment: you do not need to explicitly set the BindingContext of the ViewCell - the ListView will take care of this for you.  Your binding expressions should look like `Text="{Binding di.amt}"`

Comment: Ok. I'm still getting the `[AppName.GridItem]` in the ListView, ideas?

Comment: is that displaying in one of the Labels, or is that displaying for the entire cell?  If it's the 2nd case, it is probably a problem with your template setup, which you did not post code for.

Comment: the entire call

Comment: I did not use a template. I should look into this.

Comment: I have read that a ViewCell would work inside a ListView - so I just defined a custom ViewCell.

Comment: You have to use a template to tell the ListView to use your ViewCell, otherwise it will default to a TextCell, which sounds like the problem

Comment: @Jason, thanks. I will do some more research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve the databinding with listview(MVVM),
Here is running screenshot.
[image]

First of all, you can create a model `DItem`.I achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, layout will changed when the value was changed

```
      public class DItem: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string _itemName;
    public string itemName
    {
        set
        {
            if (_itemName != value)
            {
                _itemName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("itemName");

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _itemName;
        }
    }

    int _amt;
    public int amt
    {
        set
        {
            if (_amt != value)
            {
                _amt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("amt");

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _amt;
        }
    }

    string _amtType;
    public string amtType
    {
        set
        {
            if (_amtType != value)
            {
                _amtType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("amtType");

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _amtType;
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then, achieve the ModelView.`DItemViewModel`, We do not need create `GridItems` just add the `DItem` to the `ObservableCollection<DItem>`

```
  public class DItemViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DItem> lv { get; set; }
    public DItemViewModel()
    {

        DItem di = new DItem() { itemName = "someName", amt = 1, amtType = "xf" };

        lv = new ObservableCollection<DItem>();
        lv.Add(di);
    }


}
```

Here is layout of listview. add the `ItemsSource="{Binding lv}"` for listview.

```
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding lv}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame  HeightRequest="50" Padding="0" Margin="1" BorderColor="blue" CornerRadius="4" BackgroundColor="lightBlue">
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                                <RowDefinition Height="34"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Button x:Name="btnItem" Text="{Binding itemName}" Clicked="btnItem_Clicked" Padding="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20" />
                                <Label x:Name="lbAmt" Text="{Binding amt}" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="lightBlue" />
                                <Label x:Name="lbType" Text="{Binding amtType}" Grid.Column="3" Margin="2" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" BackgroundColor="lightBlue" />
                            </Grid>

                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>

                </ViewCell>

            </DataTemplate>    

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

And here is background code for the listview.

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new DItemViewModel();
    }
    private void btnItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here are helpful articles about MVVM in Xamarin forms.
https://almirvuk.blogspot.com/2017/02/xamarinforms-listview-simple-mvvm.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm